What is the difference between an inferred object type in Typescript, and an explicitly stated interface with the same signature?
Consider the below.
function func( obj?: { [key: string]: string } ) { }

interface RandomObj {
  foo: string
}

const randomObj: RandomObj = {
  foo: 'foo'
};

const state = func(randomObj);

Playground.
The above throws a TS error as it stands, but if RandomObj is removed from randomObj it is suddenly OK.
What is the difference between using the interface and relying on inference? To my eye, the two signatures look identical.

see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300 and the linked q/a above

@jcalz Thanks a lot, legend as always. I was trying to convert the interface into a type alias, to make the assignment work (the interface is nested). Instead of asking here in comments, I added a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78985655/how-can-a-nested-interface-be-converted-to-a-type-alias-in-typescript). Your thoughts would be appreciated, I am probably missing some basic trick.
