How can a nested interface be converted to a type alias in TypeScript?
I am trying to assign a nested interface type (from a third party library that I cannot change), to a type with a compatible index signature.
One way to make such an assignment work, is to convert the interface into a type alias first (ref. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).
How can a nested interface be converted to a type alias?
Below follows an example (playground).
interface InnerIObj {
  b: string;
}

interface IObj {
  x: {
    a: string;
  } & InnerIObj;
}

type IndexSignature = {
  [key: string]:
    | IndexSignature
    | string
};

declare const obj: IObj;

type TObj = Pick<IObj, keyof IObj>; // Did not work, as the nested interfaces remains interfaces.

const objAlias: TObj = obj;

const error: IndexSignature = objAlias


@jcalz You are absolutely right, it was an unintentional mistake. It should be fixed now. Your playground link seems to address the issue, thank you!

The type Pick<T, keyof T> is equivalent to the "identity" mapped type {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}.  If you want to apply that recursively, you can define a nested "identity" mapped type like
type NestedId<T> = { [K in keyof T]: NestedId<T[K]> }

And then apply it to your type:
type TObj = NestedId<IObj>; 
/* type TObj = {
    x: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
    };
} */
const objAlias: TObj = obj;
const noError: IndexSignature = objAlias; // okay!

That works for your example. I put the scare quotes around "identity" because there are edge cases where the output is not equivalent to the input. For example, call signatures are not mapped, so functions will lose their function-ness:
interface IObjWithMethods {
  foo(): void;
  bar(x: string): void;
  baz: {
    qux(): void;
  }
}
type TObjWithMethods = NestedId<IObjWithMethods>;
/* type TObjWithMethods = {
    foo: {};
    bar: {};
    baz: {
        qux: {};
    };
} */

If that matters to you, you can make NestedId<T> more complicated (but you'll need to decide if you want to just leave functions untransformed, or transform their parameter and return types, and then you get into problems with generic functions and overloaded functions, and ). But since the question as asked doesn't require that, I won't digress further here about it.
Playground link to code
